# Which controller to place API endpoints

Tags: rest, url, controller, uri, asp.net-core-webapi

In a .Net Core 2.1 Web API, say I have two models:

```
Student
School
```

and two controllers:

```
StudentsController
SchoolsController
```

The API exposes these endpoints to access these resources:

```
/api/students
/api/students/{id}
/api/students/{id}/school

/api/schools
/api/schools/{id}
/api/schools/{id}/students
```

I have two questions:

1. Should

   /api/schools/{id}/students

go in the SchoolsController or StudentsController? I was tempted to put it under the SchoolsController as the route suggests this is regarding a school. However, it returns students, so maybe it's better served in the StudentsContoller? Or should I create  a new SchoolsStudentsController perhaps?

2. Would

   /api/schools{id}/students

perhaps be better if it were exposed as:

```
/api/students?schoolId={id}
```

I feel like the first choice is more "RESTful", but perhaps the second choice is fine too, as all I'm doing is returning a list of students, filtered to a particular school. If I went with this second choice, there would be no doubt as to which controller to stick the code in (it would logically go into the StudentsController)

I'm not sure if there any best practices in RESTful architecture regarding this... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no hard and fast rule here. It's entirely up to you. Regardless of where you place the actions, you can assign them whatever routes they should have via attribute routing. Likely, you will break them into separate controllers, simply to minimize the amount of code in any given controller, but if you're only dealing with a handful of routes, it may be perfectly fine for them to all reside in the same controller. Again, it's a judgement call; one only you can make.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chris